# C# Validate attribute inside property of custom data type (enum) of a nested class

Tags: c#, validation, properties, attributes, inner-classes

I need some help with the below. I have a base class, say MyClass, who has inside a nested class, say StandardOne. In StandardOne I have some properties which I wish to validate with attributes.
The properties are on common data types, i.e. string, char etc, BUT I have some of them that are based on simple enums. At that point, the validation of the attributes does not work, as per the error hint because of a cast. I tried everything, but, alas, not succeeded.

1. Could anyone help me on resolving the error?
2. I see I do again and again the same kind of code on validating the attributes; any advice on how (maybe?) turn this to an extension? I don't know.. Any advice welcomed.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public Standard_One Standard {get;set;}

        private string  _Name;

        public MyClass(string system_name)
        {
            this._Name = system_name;
            this.Standard = new Standard_One();
        }

        public class Standard_One
        {
            private string _MyProperty1;

            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Field is mandatory.")]
            [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "Field value should be between Minimum 1 and Maximum 32 characters.", MinimumLength = 1)]
            [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$", ErrorMessage = "Non-valid characters included.")]
            public string MyProperty1
            {
                get
                { return _MyProperty1; }
                set
                {
                    var context = new ValidationContext(value, null, null);
                    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
                    var attributes = typeof(Standard_One)
                        .GetProperty("MyProperty1")
                        .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                        .OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
                        .ToArray();
                    
                    // All ok
                    if (!Validator.TryValidateValue(value, context, results, attributes))       
                    {
                        foreach (var result in results)
                        {Console.WriteLine("MyProperty1 error: {0}", result.ErrorMessage); }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("MyProperty1 set to {0}.", value);
                        _MyProperty1 = value;
                    }
                }
            }

            public enum field_sys_type { A, B, G }
            
            [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Field is mandatory.")]
            [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "Field value should be between Minimum 1 and Maximum 32 characters.", MinimumLength = 1)]
            [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$", ErrorMessage = "Non-valid characters included.")]
            public field_sys_type MyProperty2
            {
                get
                { return _MyProperty2; }
                set
                {
                    var context = new ValidationContext(value, null, null);
                    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
                    var attributes = typeof(Standard_One)
                        .GetProperty("MyProperty2")
                        .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                        .OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
                        .ToArray();
                    
                    // THROWS System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'field_sys_type' to type 'System.String'.'
                    if (!Validator.TryValidateValue(value, context, results, attributes))       
                    {
                        foreach (var result in results)
                        {Console.WriteLine("MyProperty2 error: {0}", result.ErrorMessage); }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("MyProperty2 set to {0}.", value);
                        _MyProperty2 = value;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }   // end of MyClass
}
```

Comment: What is the sense of having 'StringLength' or 'RegularExpression' validators on enum property? It's not a string property, so it doesn't have length and certainly would not match any regular expression.

Comment: @Quercus You are definitely right, copy/pasted the code concerning the attributes (I have a lot but certainly not for the enum-declared properties). You are absolutely right. Sorry for the bit-confusing example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't validate inside the property setter. You need to validate your entire object
take a look at examples:
https://www.geekinsta.com/manually-validate-with-data-annotations/

```
 this._Name = system_name;
 this.Standard = new Standard_One();

 var ctx = new ValidationContext(this.Standard);

 // A list to hold the validation result.
 var results = new List < ValidationResult > ();

 if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(this.Standard, ctx, results, true)) {
   foreach(var errors in results) {
     Console.WriteLine("Error {0}", errors);
     return;
   }
 }
```